# Detecting when POCO entities are being initialized in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, poco

Let's say I have a POCO with a property as such

```
public class Person
{
    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
       get { return _firstName; }
       set
       {
           _firstName = value;
           // DO STUFF;
       }
    }
}
```

When the object is being initialized by EF, I only want `_firstName` to be set and nothing else, only after the object is initialized do I want a set to run the rest `// DO STUFF;`.

Comment: EF really isn't designed for this. It's not impossible, but it's almost always more work than restructuring your other code to avoid a need for this. Can you explain a bit what you are hoping to accomplish by making `FirstName` behave differently depending on when it's called? Knowing the real problem may give an easier alternative approach.

Comment: I think that the best option is to create a VIEW in your database with the same structure of your POCO class and return value only the FirstName column and null for the other columns. Read from the VIEW instead of the original table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply

1. Declare the property setter as `protected`; and
2. Expose your `// DO STUFF` behavior as a proper method `SetFirstName(string firstName)`?

Something like this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; protected set; }

    public string SetFirstName(string value)
    {
       _firstName = value;
       // DO STUFF;
    }
}
```

Much cleaner, don't need to "hack" EF at all.

Comment: This won't work as my properties are bound to a windows form control, what would work though is creating a different property to bind the control to which will then get/set the EF property.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. I believe your workaround will probably work. But if I was you, I would separate the object bound to the form control from the EF entity, since they clearly would have distinct responsabilities (presentation rules vs. DB persistance).